# Windows Dev Center does not show any errors saying app is non-compliant

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

I've got an e-mail

> Your app /app-name/ is non-compliant. We reviewed your app /app-name/
>   but found some problems. Please remedy the failures listed in our
>   report and resubmit the updated app.

I can't see any issues here. How can I fix this?

[image: Report1]
[image: Report2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first screenshot you see an option under status "view latest certification report".

Click on report and it will show you reason of  non-compliant.

[image]

If you have received this recently, many of developers have received similar email. If your non-complaint reason is same as below. All you need to do is submit questionnaire ( you don't need to submit another build )

"Content Policies: 11.11 Mandatory Age Ratings

You must obtain an age rating for your app or game when you submit it in Dev Center. You are responsible for accurately completing the rating questionnaire to obtain the appropriate rating.

Locations: Metadata

Notes To Developer

As part of our continuing efforts to improve the Store experience for our joint customers, we notified you several times to complete the Dev Center age rating questionnaire for your apps that did not have ratings based on the questionnaire."